# ADODB issue in C# - Suspecting issue is data convertion

Tags: c#, oracle

I am looking at a very old windows application and trying to figure out an issue.

The error I am getting is "Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value."

And the Code and the other details are below

```
public static bool CopyFromType(object newValues, ref ADODB.Recordset20 returnValues)
    {

        bool flag = false;

        returnValues.AddNew();

        foreach (ADODB.InternalField aField in returnValues.Fields)
        {
            Type type = newValues.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if (property.Name.ToUpper() == aField.Name.ToUpper())
                {
                    if (property.GetValue(newValues, null) != null && property.GetValue(newValues, null).ToString() != "")
                    {
                        //cast old value type to new value
                        aField.Value = property.GetValue(newValues, null);

                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }

        }
        returnValues.Update();

        return flag;
    }
```

The error occurs at the line aField.Value = property.GetValue(newValues, null); for a specific Field (PROJECT_ID). The datatype in the database is adNumeric. I tried converting to Int at assigning the value still no use.

[image]

Any help will be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever property.GetValue(newValues, null) returns is exceeding the allowed defined length of the field, and/or, you need to test and cast the return value to an int.

Also not sure if that flag is coded correct because if one iteration fails but the next one succeeds its sets the flag to true. If you are wanting to check if ANY of the values failed you should return after the first failure, cancelling the insert.

Code below also eliminates the need to check for null or zero length string.

```
public static bool CopyFromType(object newValues, ref ADODB.Recordset20 returnValues)
{

    returnValues.AddNew();

    foreach (ADODB.InternalField aField in returnValues.Fields)
    {
        Type type = newValues.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (property.Name.ToUpper() == aField.Name.ToUpper())
            {
                    //cast old value type to new value
                    int rst;
                    if (int.TryParse(property.GetValue(newValues, null), out rst))
                    { 
                        aField.Value = rst;
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Something wrong won't cast to int
                        //Kick out of function
                        returnValues.CancelUpdate();
                        return = false;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    returnValues.Update();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: HI Kim,

Thank you for a quick response, I tried this before and again now. Whereas the error still exists when the value is assigned to aField.Value = rst; 

This only happens for one field the one in the database (PROJECT_ID) and the value being passed in 10025

Comment: After looking at the code again mine may not work as some fields in your object may not be int. I would do a test and manually check and set Project_ID to 10025 and see if the problem is in the destination field, or the source data.  Also, make sure Project_ID is not an autonumber.

Comment: It shouldn't be an autonumber I was able to insert the value in db directly. Thats the reason I think its the issue with value conversion. The specific field is Number in db with Precision ans scale set to (11,0).  So the value should be under the allowedd range.

Still trying diffferent ways to debug to the issue.

Comment: What is the passed object type of newvalues? Maybe strongly type that parameter for the purposes of testing?